Compare two List of Objects in Java
I need some help with an issue I'm facing when comparing two lists of objects (TestFoo type). The goal is to check both list is equals or not
The Goal:
I need to compare existingItems and newItems (both of type TestFoo) to identify both are contains same contents or not
What I’m Doing:
Both the existingESItems and newItems are converted into sorted sets (SortedSet).
I’m using a comparator to sort these sets based on the uniqueItemDetailId property.
After sorting, I compare the sets using .equals().
However, even though the lists contain different values, the comparison (sortedExistingESItems.equals(sortedNewESItems)) is not triggering the if block, and the code isn't behaving as expected.
Comparator<TestFoo> budgetItemComparator = Comparator.comparing(TestFoo::getUniqueItemDetailId);

SortedSet<TestFoo> sortedExistingESItems = new TreeSet<>(itemComparator);
sortedExistingESItems.addAll(existingESItems);

SortedSet<TestFoo> sortedNewESItems = new TreeSet<>(budgetItemComparator);
sortedNewESItems.addAll(newItems);

if (!sortedExistingESItems.equals(sortedNewESItems)) {
    finalSavingTestFooItems.addAll(newItems);
    testFooRepository.deleteAll(existingESItems);
}

Here’s the skeleton of the TestFoo class:
public class TestFoo {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private String uniqueId;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private String uniqueIdDetailId;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private String uniqueIdSyncGuId;
    @Field(type = Keyword, index = false)
    private String name;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private String yearId;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private Set<String> types;
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private Set<String> managers;
    @Field(type = Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private Set<TestHigh> hierarchies;
    @Field(type = Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private Set<TestTeam> teamMembers;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TestFoo that = (TestFoo) o;
        return Objects.equals(uniqueId, that.uniqueId) &&
               Objects.equals(uniqueIdDetailId, that.uniqueIdDetailId) &&
               Objects.equals(uniqueIdSyncGuId, that.uniqueIdSyncGuId) &&
               Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
               Objects.equals(yearId, that.yearId) &&
               Objects.equals(types, that.types) &&
               Objects.equals(managers, that.managers) &&
               Objects.equals(hierarchies, that.hierarchies) &&
               Objects.equals(teamMembers, that.teamMembers);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uniqueId, uniqueIdDetailId, uniqueIdSyncGuId, name, yearId, types, managers, hierarchies, teamMembers);
    }
}
    
    


When posting here, strip your code down to the bare minimum needed to show your issue. We really don't care about your actual app, we care only about your technical issue. [MCVE]

The equality of a Set does not depend on an element order so there was no point in “sorting” the sets to begin with. But when you use a TreeSet, it will consider two objects equal when the comparator says that they are equal. Since you’re using two different comparators for the sets, the results are unpredictable. Even when you used lists where the order matters it would be unclear what result you expected when sorting them by different properties.

@Holger Thanks for the response ,
I don't want in any order , just need to check wether the both the list are equals or not [ contents ].
So I just removed the comparator and comparable interface from pojo and used HashSet to check the equals.

It would help if your question included one or more examples. Each example should have input (each of the two collections to be compared), expected output, and actual output.

Please provide more detail.  What exactly constitutes equal lists?   Same Order? Lists must be same size?   Are duplicate objects allowed?  Must duplicates be in same quantify of both lists.  All of these depend on how best to provide help.  Also, any solution would work regardless of your class size and instance fields.  So why not include a smaller class with two or three fields to make it easier to test (for you and us).

You can use CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection() from Apache
List<TestFoo> actual = null;
List<TestFoo> expected = null;

In case TestFoo contains an implementation of equals(), then you can use following:
org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(actual, expected);

In case you want to use custom Comparator, then you can use overloaded method:
Equator<TestFoo> equator = null;    // <-- this is a Comparator from Apache lib
org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(actual, expected, equator);

P.S. Approach with using Set is not good, because Set contains an unique elements only. But List can contain duplicates.

I not that familiar with Apache but I don't think this will work unless there is a way to pass a comparator.  The first line of the OPs code shows the Comparator for the uniqueItemDetailId property which suggests it may allow comparison on predetermined fields.  Posting a link to the JavaDoc might also help.

@WJS in the question we can see, that TestFoo contains an equals() method. So my approach will be working. Additionnaly I have added an example using custom Cmparator.

Instead TreeSet I would able to achieve [check the to list has the same content or not] using HashSet with override the equals and hash code method.
Set<TestFoo> existingItems = readsFromDb(syncGuid);

Set<TestFoo> newItemsSet = new HashSet<newItems>;


if (!newItemsSet.equals(existingItems)) {
  
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
